# Unity 2D enemy movement script not flipping when moving right to left

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to write a script for my enemy movements. Here is my code:

```
public class EnemiesMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
     private bool isFacingRight = false;
     public float speed = 10f;
     private float startPoint;
     private float endPoint;
     public float unitMovement = 2f;
     private Rigidbody2D enemy;
     private Animator anim;
     bool moveRight;
// Start is called before the first frame update
     void Start()
     {
         enemy = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
         anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
         startPoint = enemy.position.x;
         endPoint = startPoint + unitMovement;
     }

// Update is called once per frame
     void Update()
     {
         if (enemy.position.x >= endPoint)
             moveRight = false;

         if (enemy.position.x <= startPoint)
             moveRight = true;

         if (moveRight)
         {
             enemy.velocity = new Vector2(-transform.localScale.x, 0) * speed;
             if (!isFacingRight)
            Flip();
         }

         if (!moveRight)
         {
             enemy.velocity = new Vector2(transform.localScale.x, 0) * speed;
             if (isFacingRight)
                 Flip();
         }
     }

     void Flip()
     {
         isFacingRight = !isFacingRight;
         Vector3 scale = transform.localScale;
         scale.x *= -1;
         transform.localScale = scale;
     }
}
```

The movement of the enemy is right, but after the enemy flips its sprites, it doesn't change the direction of its movement. Basically, it continues to the right, even though its sprite has turned left. Can someone show me how I can fix this?

My enemy spite has a positive scale facing to the left.

Answer (score 0):

Velocity is affected by the scale property.

So if you change the scale negative, everything on this `GameObject` flips, it's not necessary to change the velocity direction.

Are you getting bewildered? You can try another method to flip the sprite.

```
GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().flipX = true;
```

This only flips the sprite renderer, other things are working as normal in its world space.

---

Another suggests as Unity documented it's better to change Rigidbody's property in the `FixedUpdate`.

Comment: I have tried to applied the solutions you suggested but the problems still remains